# Konva - use fillPatternScaleY without distorting shapes?

Tags: canvas, konvajs

I am using the Vue library and scaling a rectangle to fill an image. But I dont want shapes and other elements to distort.

```
    <v-layer ref="layer">
        <v-rect :config="{
                width: configKonva.width,
                height: configKonva.height,
                fillPatternImage: image,
                fillPatternScaleY: configKonva.height / img.height,
                fillPatternScaleX: configKonva.width / img.width
            }">
        </v-rect>
        <v-circle :config="configCircle"></v-circle>
    </v-layer>
```

[image]

Any pointers?

Comment: Scaling one axis and not another as you are doing is always going to cause a distortion. You should find the ratio of the viewport width & heights to the canvas width and heights and scale BOT x & y by the same amount.  B prepared for some clipping on the long edge of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the same values for `fillPatternScaleY` and `fillPatternScaleX`.  Currently, they are different in your code. You may try to use this:

```
Math.max(configKonva.height / img.height, configKonva.height / img.height)
```

Or you can use `Math.min`. It depends on your visualization requirements.